# PixiJS Fill Background screen

Tags: javascript, html, pixi.js

I am wondering how I can fill my background image to full screen. 
I have functions in place to resize it once you resize the browser. However on load it doesn't show the image as full.. here is the code:

```
function init() {

    renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
    renderer.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;
    stage = new PIXI.Container();

    renderer.view.style.position = "absolute";
    renderer.view.style.display = "block";
    renderer.autoResize = true;
    renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    window.addEventListener("resize", function(event){ 
    scaleToWindow(renderer);
});

    PIXI.loader
        .add(["img/background.png", "img/buttons/spin.png", "img/buttons/home.png", "img/buttons/soundon.png",
            "img/buttons/soundoff.png", "img/buttons/paytable.png", "img/buttons/stakefield.png", "img/buttons/up.png",
            "img/buttons/down.png", "img/buttons/no.png", "img/buttons/yes.png", "img/quitgame.png", "img/sym/blue_jelly.png",
            "img/sym/black_jelly.png", "img/sym/green_jelly.png", "img/sym/purple_jelly.png", "img/sym/red_jelly.png", "img/sym/yellow_jelly.png"])
        .on("complete", assetLoad)
        .load();
}
```

Then the assetLoad function is bringing in assets - example of the background coming in:

```
function assetLoad() {

    var background = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources["img/background.png"].texture);
    background.scale.set(1.05, 1.05);
    background.position.set(0, 0);

    var balancetxt = new PIXI.Text("£ " + balance.toString(), {
        fontFamily: "Arial",
        fill: 0xFFFFFF,
        fontSize: 50,
        align: 'left'
    });
    balancetxt.anchor.set(-4.5, -0.3);
    background.addChild(balancetxt);

}
```

Comment: You mean that the resizing works fine, but initial load does not? Can't you just call scaleToWindow, after the whole game has been setup?

Comment: On initial load the background doesn't fill the whole window it should. What I mean by resize is when we resize the window the background image responds well.

Comment: Can you setup a working example in plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: https://craigdobo.github.io/JellySlot/ - You can see the game here.